# Cocoa: Context Menu on Source List Data - Not Headers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsmenu

I connected a menu to the tableview, but the problem is that the context menu is also shown when I right click on the headers in the source list. is there any way to disable this?

So when isLeaf returns false (group header), it should not show the menu.

Comment: You might need to disable it programmatically using `[[myTableView headerView] setMenu:nil];`;

Comment: @trojanfoe - thanks, but doesn't seem to work. Still displays. (i do this after nib loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me the best place for menu logic is delegate, so you can subclass `NSTableView` and make something like this (in this example there is `NSOutlineView` but it doesn't meter)

```
@protocol MYOutlineViewDelegate;

@interface MYOutlineView : NSOutlineView

@property (assign) id<MYOutlineViewDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol MYOutlineViewDelegate <NSOutlineViewDelegate>

- (NSMenu *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView menuForItem:(id)item;

@end


@implementation MYOutlineView

@dynamic delegate;

- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSMenu* menu = nil;

    NSPoint clickPoint = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    id item = [self itemAtRow:[self rowAtPoint:point]];

    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(outlineView:menuForItem:)]) {
        menu = [self.delegate outlineView:self menuForItem:item];
    }

    return menu;
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to replicate the default right click selection behavior? When I use selectRowIndexes, it transfers the active row to the right clicked row, but this is not what is default - like in xcode when you right click a file - it gets a border selection. This was also the default when I did not override menuForEvent. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I’d try setting yourself up as a delegate of the menu and in `- (void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu*)menu;` remove all the items.

If that fails, just subclass NSTableView and implement `- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)event;` as you like.